# What is the best python interface for the latest Gene Ontology?

Tags: python, biopython

How is Gene Ontology annotation accessed from python now? I need to annotate each gene in a specific list. Is there any good library with tutorials and examples?

There is a problem with getting Gene Ontology annotation from python now. Biopython does not read GAF v. 2.2 files (latest version), and I could not find any good tutorials or documentation for goatools. SQL interface is in legacy mode now, meaning that it is also obsolete. Is there any solution to it?

Comment: It seems that simply opening GAF files using pandas.read_csv works relatively well. There is still an issue with mandatory and optional fields, with the field names, etc., but at least it somehow works.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to the GOAtools gaf20iterator() function to be able to read GAFv2.2. I took the code from https://github.com/tanghaibao/goatools and just adapted it a little. I just wanted to be able to parse, so it worked just fine.

#%% GAF 2.2 reader

```
GAF22FIELDS = [
    "DB",
    "DB_Object_ID",
    "DB_Object_Symbol",
    "Qualifier",
    "GO_ID",
    "DB:Reference",
    "Evidence_Code",
    "With",
    "Aspect",
    "DB_Object_Name",
    "DB_Object_Synonym",
    "DB_Object_Type",
    "Taxon",
    "Date",
    "Assigned_By",
    "Annotation_Extension",
    "Gene_Product_Form_ID",
]

def gaf22iterator(handle):
    for inline in handle:
        if inline[0] == "!":
            continue
        inrec = inline.rstrip("\n").split("\t")
        if len(inrec) == 1:
            continue
        inrec[3] = inrec[3].split("|")  # Qualifier
        inrec[5] = inrec[5].split("|")  # DB:reference(s)
        inrec[7] = inrec[7].split("|")  # With || From
        inrec[10] = inrec[10].split("|")  # Synonym
        inrec[12] = inrec[12].split("|")  # Taxon
        yield dict(zip(GAF22FIELDS, inrec))
```

I leave a use case below:

```
 for entry in gaf22iterator(tax_gaf_fp):   
      uniprot_id = entry.pop('DB_Object_ID')
      pop_funcs[uniprot_id] = entry
      print(pop_funcs[uniprot_id])
```